# how to get call id from genesys sdk platform

Tags: genesys, workspace-desktop-edition, genesys-platform-sdk

i want to get the Call id when the call is answered from agent with using the WDE (Workspace Desktop Edition) Platform SDK for .NET [ C# ] without using SIP Server ?

to call the Rest API 
https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/HTCC/latest/API/CallsAnswer

so that i need to know /{id}
for answer call and get Connid and MSISDN from the response

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all calls or search for a specific call by GETing /api/v2/me/calls or /api/v2/me?subresources=*. Details [here](https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/HTCC/latest/API/CallResource).

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to T-server and monitor agent extension's events. When the agent answers the call, T-server sends an established message to you. This established message includes DeviceId(ThisDn),AgentId,CallId,ConnId and other informations of call.

In the link below, you can see that how to connect t-server and monitor extension's events.

[Genesys Platform : Get Call Details From Sip Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848589/genesys-platform-get-call-details-from-sip-server)

Comment: You should include some of the important info from the link into this answer, that way if the linked page goes down this answer is still useful.

Comment: Thank you, Andy, for your advice. In order to the answer is already written, ı don't want to be like stealing it. I will consider the advice in my next answers.

Comment: The question specifically says "without using SIP Server".